# Hidden Group Membership support

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://blogs.office.com/2017/04/06/whats-new-in-office-365-groups-for-april-2017/

Hidden membership—If you want group membership to be confidential (for example, if the members are students), you can hide the Office 365 group members from users who aren’t members of the group.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219359(v=exchg.160).aspx
New-UnifiedGroup -HiddenGroupMembershipEnabled

Using this exchange online powershell to create O365 group with hidden membership?

Will graph API support it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is supported in Microsoft Graph, but the documentation is in the process of being updated for this capability.

To create a group with hidden membership, POST /groups and set "visibility" to "HiddenMembership". Owners and admins can add/remove/list members, but no one else can.

To enable an app (daemon app - no signed-in users) to read the members of a hidden membership group, you need to grant the app the *Member.Read.Hidden* permission as documented [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/permission_scopes).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Powerful MS Graph API.